# Python - Assigning `set.union` as a class attribute

Tags: python, set, python-descriptors

When assigning `set.union` as an attribute to a class, and call this attribute from an instance variable of that class will raise an error: `TypeError: descriptor 'union' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'Foo' object`. Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

```py
class Foo:
    bar = set.union

set.union({1}, {2})
# {1, 2}
Foo.bar({1}, {2})
# {1, 2}
Foo().bar({1}, {2})
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
# TypeError: descriptor 'union' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to 'Foo' object
```

This does not happens when assigning `set.union` as an instance attribute:

```py
class Foobar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = set.union

Foobar().bar({1}, {2})
# {1, 2}
```

What causes this error? Why does this only happens for class attribute?